# Playing HLS without Android OS support for .ts files

Tags: android, codec, http-live-streaming

I have developed an HLS player for Android 2.3.  It works.  However, I am finding that certain Android devices lack support for .ts files.  On these phones my player does not work.  So, my question is this:  Is there a way that I can include support for these files within my app (perhaps a codec or a library of some sort)?  After exhaustive searching, I'm really not sure where to go.

Thanks.

Comment: If you dont mind could you please give some pointers for playing .ts files on android ICS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to port FFMPEG to Android with the NDK, I think that's the best solution for your playing issues. I'm now in that way, I could report you my advances .

Comment: Yes, I agree.  I, too, found this to be the only viable solution, though it will require some time to implement.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [vitamio](http://vov.io/vitamio/). I think that your player will work if vitamio is installed on the the devices that don't already support the ts files.

Comment: Yes, but I need to make my solution self containing.  No third party plug-ins or apps.  Thanks, though.

Comment: @javaMe In that case you should buy a license from vov.io to include it in your application.